# Configuring SiteMesh for specific action mappings in Struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2, sitemesh

I'm trying to configure sitemesh to only take effect for a certain subset of action mappings in my Struts 2 application.

Say for example, I have the following struts.xml snippet:

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="showForm">
    <result>/view/form.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
<package name="widgets" namespace="/widgets" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="showForm">
    <result>/view/form.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

I would like the output of "/showForm.action" to be decorated by SiteMesh but for "/widgets/showForm.action" to be returned empty instead. The critical part here is that I want the JSP file to be reused by both action mappings.

But try as I might, I can't seem to get SiteMesh's  tag to recognize a mapping. I have to specify the file "/view/form.jsp" to be excluded instead and that means I won't be able to reuse the JSP file.

Is there any way I can get around this?

I'm using Struts 2.0.14.

Thanks,
Wong

Comment: are you asking decorators.xml under WEB-INF folder?<decorators defaultdir="/decorators">
    <decorator name="null">
        <pattern>/widgets/hello.action</pattern>
    </decorator>

    <decorator name="main" page="main.vm">
        <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as for [Using SiteMesh with RequestDispatcher's forward()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619699/using-sitemesh-with-requestdispatchers-forward).  You can change the way the sitemesh filter is mapped to incoming requests.

I think you'd want:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this out first.